# Как преобразовать numpy массив с 1 канальными изображениями, в 3х канальные

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

имеем

```py
train_images.shape # (22967, 48, 48) numpy.ndarray
train_images[0].shape # (48,48) numpy.ndarray
```

я понимаю как преобразовать 1 изображение

```py
img=train_images[0]
img3=np.dstack((img,img,img))
img3.shape # (48,48,3)
```

но изображений слишком много чтобы это делать через цикл.
В итоге train_image пойдет на вход нейронке vgg16, а она требует (48,48,3)

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected vgg16_input to have shape (48, 48, 3) but got array with shape (48, 48, 1)`
Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

Пусть нам дан массив из двух изображений:

```
In [27]: a = np.arange(1, 2*3*3+1).reshape(2,3,3)

In [28]: a.shape
Out[28]: (2, 3, 3)

In [31]: a[0]
Out[31]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [32]: a[0].shape
Out[32]: (3, 3)
```

Чтобы получить из него массив размерности `(2,3,3,3)` (последняя размерность - число цветовых каналов):

```
In [33]: r = np.stack((a,)*3, axis=3)

In [34]: r.shape
Out[34]: (2, 3, 3, 3)

In [35]: r[0].shape
Out[35]: (3, 3, 3)
```